# can't convert webbot script to an executable

Tags: web-scraping, webautomation, webbot

I am trying to convert a python script which uses the `webbot` library for web automation.

As I tried to convert my running Python (3.6.5) script to an .exe file using pyinstaller I was getting an error that the path of the webbot module could not be found.

In order to overcome this problem I tried to specify the path of the module in the spec file, without success. An easier workaround suggests copying the downloaded folder webbot in the same folder where the .exe file is.

Its a very handy tool to use , i don't wanna ditch it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for this to work you should not convert it as one file like this

```
pyinstaller --onefile file.py
```

but like this

```
pyinstaller file.py
```

After doing this the .exe could be launched without any problems.

An other error was coming because of trying to import webbot in my script. Probably this is a noob mistake, but one has to:

```
from webbot import Browser
```