# How do I run a Python program created by Pyinstaller that uses Webbot?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to run a fairly simple Windows Python 3.7 script that uses Webbot.  The script works beautifully from within Python's IDLE, so I know the code that I've written works and there's nothing wrong with it, but I want to run it as an .exe instead.  However after packaging it with Pyinstaller (which normally works wonderfully), although the Pyinstaller process runs, the actual program produced won't run at all.

I had a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53138328/cant-convert-webbot-script-to-an-executable) but this didn't help much.  If I compile using:

```
pyinstaller file.py
```

as suggested, when I run the resulting .exe, the program closes instantly, with no error message.

If I instead try:

```
pyinstaller --onefile file.py
```

or:

```
pyinstaller file.py -F
```

Then when I run the compiled .exe I get this message:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\KimJiwoo\\Appdata\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI51362\\drivers\\chrome_windows.exe'
```

So I guess I need chrome_windows.exe?

I figured I could just give the program this file, but the _MEI folder is a temp directory that seems to be created each time.  I've tried putting chrome_windows.exe in other places, like in System32 or the same directory where file.py or the created .exe is, the same error occurs.

So I guess I have to make this program see chrome_windows.exe somehow but I'm not sure how.  I do already have

```
from webbot import Browser
```

in my script, but clearly I need something more than this.  Not sure what.

Note that I'm not that fussed whether the Python program includes chrome_windows.exe within its own created .exe or not.  I mean, that would be nice, but if it's simpler coding-wise to just shove chrome_windows.exe into a directory on the computer the program is running from, and have something in the program pointing to it there, then that would also be fine.  I feel like the answer to this is probably simple so I'm after the most simple, elegant solution possible.

Comment: If you plan on not including the chromedriver, make sure it's in the right directory to be accessed. If you do plan on including it, I'd suggest taking a look at https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html. You need a spec file, which contains binaries and libraries that you need to compile with your .py -> .exe.

Comment: How do I know what the "right directory to be accessed" is?  The directory given in the error message literally doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Webbot, but I do use chromedrivers for python. When I need to access a chromedriver, I specify a path. If you don't plan on including it in the compiled binary, then you need to specify a path that you know that chromedriver is going to be in. (I use mechanize / selenium)

Comment: I really don't want to ditch Webbot, it's much easier to code than Selenium/Mechanize and when run in IDLE it does exactly what I want, amazingly well.  No idea how to specify a path for it though, Webbot's documentation doesn't talk about this.

Comment: I've looked at the source-the path for the webdriver seems to be `driverpath =  os.path.join(os.path.split(__file__)[0] , 'drivers{0}{1}'.format(os.path.sep , driverfilename))` (when you compile to exe, the files directory is in TEMP). You have a couple options. You can use the source to make your own class and change the directory path, or you can ditch Webbot and use selenium, since webbot (https://github.com/nateshmbhat/webbot/blob/master/webbot/webbot.py) uses selenium.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you!  I edited webbot.py so instead of ```driverpath =  os.path.join(os.path.split(__file__)[0] , 'drivers{0}{1}'.format(os.path.sep , driverfilename))``` it's now ```driverpath = ('C://drivers/chrome_windows.exe')``` and put the file in there, and it works great.  <3

Comment: I'll make this into an answer for you to accept, if you'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path for the webdriver in the `Webbot` source seems to be `driverpath = os.path.join(os.path.split(__file__)[0] , 'drivers{0}{1}'.format(os.path.sep , driverfilename))` (when you compile to exe, the files directory is in TEMP).

You can use the source to make your own class and change the directory path (github.com/nateshmbhat/webbot/blob/master/webbot/webbot.py).